# How to display result in GridView?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

NET WinForms.

VB code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)       Handles Button1.Click

    Label1.Text = "Beginning"

    Dim a As Integer = 20
    Dim b As Integer = 3
    Do Until b > a

        a & " " & b

        a = a - 2
        b = b + 1
    Loop
    Label2.Text = "End"
End Sub
```

I want to display the result of this row   **a & " " & b** in GridView.
How should I change the code to make this work properly?

Comment: Do you mean to take the value of this row a & " " & b (where a indicates row and b - column )?

Then use it like this:
Dim value As String = Me.DataGridView1.Item(b, a).Value

Comment: you can use generics to bind with DatGridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you store the value into DataTable and bind into the DataGridView

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)       Handles Button1.Click

    Label1.Text = "Beginning"

    'Create a new datatable here
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Result")


    Dim a As Integer = 20
    Dim b As Integer = 3
    Do Until b > a

        'Create DataRow here and put the value into DataRow
        Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow
        dr("result") = a.ToString & " " & b.ToString
        'a & " " & b
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)

        a = a - 2
        b = b + 1
    Loop

    'Bind your dt into the GridView
    DataGridView.DataSource = dt

    Label2.Text = "End"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Add DataGridView to your form, and add 2 columns, then next updated code will do that

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)          Handles Button1.Click

    Label1.Text = "Beginning"

    ' If the DataGridView is not bound to any data source, this code will clear content
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()

    Dim a As Integer = 20
    Dim b As Integer = 3
    Do Until b > a

       'a & " " & b
       ' add the row to the end of the grid with the Add() method of the Rows collection...
       DataGridView1.Rows.Add(New String(){a.ToString(), b.ToString()})

       a = a - 2
       b = b + 1
    Loop
    Label2.Text = "End"
End Sub
```